# Why does IIS lock my ASP.NET website folders?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Why does IIS lock my ASP.NET website folders? I can't view the folder contents with CuteFTP now. I need to connect to my server over Remote Desktop and use unlocker to unlock the folder.

I'm also unable to delete folders.

Is there any solution for this? Note that only some folders are locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because IIS worker process is using that folder. You can stop it through Task manager. In your web server,

1. run inetmgr
2. click your website
3. click "worker processes"
4. find out the application pool of the website, and find out it process ID
5. run task process and click "show processes from all users"
6. Kill "w3wp.exe" process with the correct process ID
   (if you can't see the PID in the list, click View->select columns->PID)
   After that, it should work.